# Asp.net core api with GraphQL and CosmosDB giving SocketException (10013)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, graphql, azure-cosmosdb

I've build a small graphQL api in asp.net core that gets some data from a Azure Cosmos database. Locally it runs fine with a CosmosEmulator.

If I connect the local running api directly to the CosmosDb running in Azure it works also fine.

When I deploy it through a devops pipeline, the graphQL api gives the following error:

```
GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve products.\r\n ---> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: InternalServerError (500); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; Reason: (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.);\r\n ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.\r\n   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- Cosmos Diagnostics ---{\"DiagnosticVersion\":\"2\",\"Summary\":{\"StartUtc\":\"2020-11-16T19:32:58.2689693Z\",\"RunningElapsedTimeInMs\":137.7423,\"UserAgent\":\"cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.12.0|3.11.4|03|X86|Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393|.NET Core 3.1.8|\",\"TotalRequestCount\":0,\"FailedRequestCount\":0},\"Context\":[]}\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

It seems that something between api and database isn't working but I can't figure it out. Should I change settings in the webapp configuration in Azure?

Comment: Is it a single call, or is it multiple calls? The error could indicate that your have run'ed out of sockets - but it depends...

Comment: It is just one call, simple select query. I use Postman to do the call.

Comment: Have you checked for firewall and connectivity in general?

Comment: Not sure where to look, the API runs in a azure webapp in the same resource group as the CosmosDb.

Comment: ok, try look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483412/azure-website-keeps-throwing-the-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-i

Comment: These answers direct to running out of Sockets, while my app never works, also not after a restart.

Comment: I did a upgrade to all the graphql libraries, and fixed breaking changes. Now it actually runs fine on Azure as well. So problem is fixed.

Comment: So it was a library version mismatch?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. Somehow I decided to do the upgrade and see if that works, and it did.